# wpa_action script: How to run wpa_cli in daemon mode?

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, raspberry-pi, wpa-cli

I was trying to build a script that runs when wifi is connected or disconnected. After a lot of searches, I got `wpa_cli -a` command to work with my script.

test.sh

```
case "$1" in
    wlan0)
        case "$2" in
            CONNECTED)
                echo WIFI is CONNECTED "$WPA_ID"  > output
                #sudo python ./do.py
                ;;
            DISCONNECTED)
                echo WIFI is Disconnected "$WPA_ID" > output
                ;;
            *)
                >&2 echo empty or undefined event for wlan0: ""
                exit 1
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
esac
```

I was tested the script by running the command `sudo wpa_cli -a /home/pi/test.sh`. I disconnected the wifi and checked the output file and it contains " WIFI disconnected message". Similar checking is done by connecting to a wifi and we observed "WIFI connected" message.

But when i tried to run the command `wpa_cli` in daemon mode, It don't work. I have used the command `sudo wpa_cli -a /home/pi/test.sh -B`. But this time output file have no change if i connected or disconnected the wifi.

But when i `ps aux|grep test.sh`, it shows the script is running.

Answer (score 2):

I have got the answer. When I run in daemon mode using `sudo wpa_cli -a /home/pi/test.sh -B`, I was checking the wrong output file( In the home directory ). In the echo, I have not mentioned the correct path for file output, So it will be redirected to the file `output` in the root `/` directory.

Thanks for all